# How to run programs only from picked folders? windows 7

Tags: windows-7, security

how can i using only OS tools make all admins and users to run system and application software only from folders %ProgramFiles% and %Windir%?

Can i use applocker for this? How do i do that?

Comment: Domain machines? Workgroup? One computer? Give details

Comment: all groups, one computer